# Prevent Windows shutdown with custom message

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7, vmware

VMWare Workstation does something quite cool when I try to shutdown Windows while a Virtual Machine is running:

[image: VMWare prevents Windows shutdown with a custom message]

Normally, we'd see a "This program is preventing Windows from shutting down" message instead of the new "1 Virtual Machine is in use".

How does VMWare do this? I haven't been able to find any APIs about it on Google.

Comment: I know when using the shutdown command on the command line one can specify custom shutdown messages to display, maybe this is related?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can read all about the changes introduced in Vista [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms700677%28VS.85%29.aspx). You really should read that article very carefully.

The APIs you are looking for are [`ShutdownBlockReasonCreate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376877%28VS.85%29.aspx), [`ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376878%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [`ShutdownBlockReasonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376879%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). Remember that these APIs are only available on Vista/2008 server up. You'll have to implement fall back behaviour on 2000/XP.

If you need to block shutdown you call `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate` passing the handle to your main window and the reason as a string. This string is what is displayed in the shutdown blocked dialog, i.e. "1 virtual machine is in use" in your screenshot.

If the operation that blocks shutdown completes then you call `ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy`.

Note that you must still implement [`WM_QUERYENDSESSION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376890(v=VS.85).aspx) to make all the pieces fit together. This is the part that actually blocks the shutdown.

On XP you should also respond to [`WM_ENDSESSION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376889%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and if your app blocked shutdown it is polite to show a message indicating why. If you don't do so then the user is left scratching his/her head as to why the computer is ignoring the instruction to shutdown.

Comment: [Don't forget to respond to WM_QUERYENDSESSION.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms700677(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Ahh, thank you! I found those through Google, but the documentation doesn't do very much in the way of noting that it affects the UI, so I thought the message would be displayed, for example, using a message box.

Comment: The key is the discursive article that I linked to in  the first sentence of the answer. That's your guide for handling shutdown. The API documentation is always a bit more terse.